# Android ListView doesn't display anything (Relative Layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I am having problems with ListView. It doesn't display. I know it's a common problem but I'm  new to Android. In most examples, the problem is solved with layout_bellow property but I do not have any other controls.
Here is my XML code:

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gkmicro.trrrrrrrrrrrrrr.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.gkmicro.trrrrrrrrrrrrrr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you adding any items to the list?

Comment: Post it's `Adapter` code.

Comment: Did you specify some row layout? I mean, are you trying to show 2 `TextView` 's of something like that? If so, please post your adapter and the adapter calling, to see if you're passing the data correctly

Comment: Why are you using ListView? RecyclerView is the way to go, so maybe you can take a look at that

Comment: I recommend using RecyclerView! http://erikcaffrey.github.io/2015/10/05/recyclerview/

Comment: Not at the moment. I have only a ListView and before I start adding rows I want to be sure that it displays correctly. For example, when I add a button I can see it the same with other controls and only ListView is not working.

Comment: Thank you I will try RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ListView` to use all width and height of your parent `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gkmicro.trrrrrrrrrrrrrr.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

By the way as recommended @Erik Jhordan Rey Caffrey use `RecyclerView`

**EDIT:** If you have any issues [here is a good sample](http://androidinterview.com/android-simple-listiview-example) to implement a simple listView inside a RelativeLayout

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: did you still have the same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I have tried all option  but the result is still the same.

Comment: please post your adapter

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adapter but I have submitted activitymain.xml and MainActivity.java files. Please take a look.

Comment: Here is a good sample to implement a simple listView inside a RelativeLayout http://www.androidinterview.com/android-simple-listiview-example/. Tell me if u have any other issues ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works I still do not know why it didn't work in my case I think it is something to do with coordinate layout. Now at least I can see the list view on the screen. It's a good example.

Comment: I will edit my answer, to add the link, please mark as solved if you find my help valuable ;)

Comment: Hi, i do find it useful but I do not understand why your answer doesn't have the vote score. Where is the option for marking the question as solved?

Answer (score 0):

As your `ListView` is  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` it stick to bottom with  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

So make `ListView` like this

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but the result is still the same.